# Cannot display more than 20 records?

Tags: apex, visualforce, integration, pagination

I am trying to display in a VF page the contacts from another org.

The problem is that I can only show the first 20 records and I would like to show 1000.

Pagination is working fine for the first 20 but after that I cannot see any other contact.

//VF page

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="ContactsREST" recordSetVar="contacts" showHeader="false">

    <apex:sectionHeader title="Contacts" subtitle="List View"/>
    <apex:pageBlock title="Viewing Contacts">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!contacts}" var="contact">
            <apex:column value="{!contact.name}" />
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
        <apex:form id="theForm">
        <apex:pageBlockSection >
            <apex:dataList var="contact" value="{!contacts}">
                {!contact.Name}
            </apex:dataList>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:panelGrid columns="2">
            <apex:commandLink action="{!first}">FIRST</apex:commandLink>
            <apex:commandLink action="{!next}">NEXT</apex:commandLink>
            <apex:commandLink action="{!previous}">PREVIOUS</apex:commandLink>
            <apex:commandLink action="{!last}">LAST</apex:commandLink>
        </apex:panelGrid>
</apex:form>   
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

//Controller

```
public class ContactsREST {

    public ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon{get{
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setEndpoint('https://meirinho-leonel-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v45.0/query?q=SELECT+Id+,+Name+FROM+Contact+LIMIT+1000');
    request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer 00D0N000001Ew!QN2OQAsqABXfXmxAZv.3LTQ4IujSyqBc76PYfpGdcUTCF4igQOF3cGswZKnzS2ozML5culT8..diUpDq');
    request.setMethod('GET');
    HttpResponse res = http.send(request);

    // Generate the HTTP response as an XML stream
    //Deserialize obtained json response
        List<Contact> ListContacts = new List<Contact>();
        string response = res.getBody();
        string str = '['+ response.substring(response.indexOf('records":[')+10,response.indexof(']}')) +']';
        ListContacts = (list<Contact>)JSON.deserialize(str,list<Contact>.class);
        ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(ListContacts);
        return setCon;    
    }set;}

     public ContactsREST(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {
        setCon = controller; 
         controller.setPageSize(10);
    }

     // Initialize setCon and return a list of records
    public List<Contact> getContactsListData() {
        return (List<Contact>) setCon.getRecords();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any issue in your code. Did you check how many records are there in the targeted org? Also, put some debug statements and check the size of the list after parsing the response.

Comment: thanks @Arabinda, the size of my list is 1000 records. That's what i got from the debug and i created all of them in order to show them in the VF page.

Comment: can you add a System.debug(ListContacts.size()); right after instantiating ListContacts variable? What is the size?

Comment: also, can you double check this? setCon = controller

Comment: @MicheleMilidoni the size of the ListContacts is 1000. i also double checked the setCon and i still same issue.

Comment: with the statement setCon = controller you are setting "setCon" variable to the standard controller, but the getter method will not be invoked.